# Summarising a POSIX (date/time) referenced vector in another date/time referenced vector

Tags: r, posixct, downsampling

Hi all R efficiency gurus (and people with a similar question to me),

This is an efficiency question. I have some very large data set. One data.frame contains data from one instrument with a POSIX date and time with values at a very high frequency. Another data.frame contains data from another instrument with a column of date and time values at much lower sampling frequency.

I wish to assign summary values of the high frequency data frame to the time periods of the low frequency data.frame. This function works, but is very slow when you have millions of data points:

```
st <- strptime("22/09/2013 12:00:00", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
st.vec <- st + runif(10,0, 60*60*24)
en.vec <- st.vec + 10*60
tm.hfreq <- strptime("22/09/2013 12:00:00", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S") + runif(400,0,     60*60*24)
vals.hfreq <-  runif(400,0, 12000)

intervalstats <- function(strt, fin, vals, tms){
  mns <- NULL
  mds <- NULL
  sds <- NULL
  for (i in seq(1,length(fin))){
    mns <- append(mns,mean(vals[(tms > strt[i])&(tms < fin[i])]))
    sds <- append(sds,sd(vals[(tms > strt[i])&(tms < fin[i])]))
    mds <- append(mds,median(vals[(tms > strt[i])&(tms < fin[i])]))

}
  res <- cbind(mns, sds, mds)  
  res 
}

intervalstats(st.vec, en.vec, vals.hfreq, tm.hfreq)
```

Does anyone have a suggestion for a more efficient, faster approach?

Comment: I guess some first hints would be to not initialize `mns` as `NULL` but as `rep(NA, length(fin))` (or something similar) and -instead of `append`- use `mns[i] = ..`. Also, you could calculate `vals[(tms > strt[i])&(tms < fin[i])]` just once and set it to a variable and, then, use it three times.

Comment: Thanks for those tips. I'll try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `apply` method looking across each row. I did need to convert the dates using `as.numeric` so it would work appropriately though. Something like:

```
lofreq <- data.frame(st.vec,en.vec)
lofreq <- sapply(lofreq, as.numeric)
hifreq <- data.frame(tm.hfreq=as.numeric(tm.hfreq),vals.hfreq)

t(apply(
  lofreq,
  1,
  function(x) {
    out <- hifreq$vals.hfreq[hifreq$tm.hfreq > x[1] & hifreq$tm.hfreq < x[2]]
    c(mns=mean(out), sds=sd(out), mds=median(out))
  }
))

#           mns       sds      mds
# [1,] 8610.664 3179.3055 9392.312
# [2,] 9398.725  844.6824 9039.992
# [3,] 6159.502 3900.0839 6159.502
# [4,] 6428.173 5802.1844 6428.173
# [5,] 5446.384 4770.9478 6783.228
# [6,] 6309.637 2017.6561 6503.751
# [7,] 6312.746 2354.9198 5553.370
# [8,] 4461.549        NA 4461.549
# [9,] 4486.433 6263.8853 4486.433
#[10,] 7279.241 1520.4536 7279.241
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a shot and see how the cpu-time compares

Comment: Looks like using this version consumes 0.11 seconds of user time for 400000 elements, while my original consumed 0.62. Not bad!

Comment: @user2449710 - great - I'd be interested to know if/how it scales to millions of cases. It may be worth investigating the `data.table` package if you are working with large data and need to speed things up.

Comment: actually I am getting bigger differences with some data files. Ive converted your suggestion to a function. It processes one time-crossreference in 0.17 seconds (47 000 high frequency points), while my old version took 23 seconds. That is subsampling to 23 sub-intervals. I've yet to use it with one of my large data sets -- but things are looking good.